# How to upgrade fontawesome with yarn?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, font-awesome, yarnpkg

package.json has following lines:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
```

I did a `yarn upgrade` but version numbers does not increase. Why? I see in their website there is already version 6.1.1.

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages

And also `yarn upgrade` warns me to upgrade. How can I upgrade if not with `yarn upgrade`?

```
yarn upgrade v1.22.17
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.3.0: Please upgrade to 6.1.0. https://fontawesome.com/docs/changelog/
warning @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core > @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@0.3.0: Please upgrade to 6.1.0. https://fontawesome.com/docs/changelog/
```

Comment: Did you try `yarn upgrade @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core --latest` with each package?

Comment: Finally I set in `package.json` the latest version, and did a yarn. That helped.